# Entity Framework virtual collection resulting in unexpected table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-core

I have an EF opbject

```
public class Country
{
    [Key]
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }
    public string CountryName { get; set; }
}
```

as well as a generic item:

```
public class Item
{
    public int ItemID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Country> AvailableIn { get; set; }
}
```

the resulting `Country` table has the fields:

```
CountryCode
CountryName 
ItemItemID
```

How do I tell EF that I would like the relation to be build as an `ItemAvailableCountry` related table as opposed to modifying the Country table?

**EDIT**

Per a comment below I've included the relevant migration code if I add just the column in question

```
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.AddColumn<int>(
            name: "ItemItemID",
            table: "Country",
            isNullable: true);
        migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
            name: "FK_Country_Item_ItemItemID",
            table: "Country",
            column: "ItemItemID",
            principalTable: "Item",
            principalColumn: "ItemID");
    }
```

As it may be relevant - this is work in EF7

Comment: Are you sure there is a `CountryName` column? it should be `Name` (as declared in your `Country` class). The `ItemItemID` is because it requires a foreign key to `Item` but you don't explicitly specify the name so it auto-choose that name (combined from the class name `Item` and its primary key `ItemID`). However I expected it to `Item_ItemID` rather than `ItemItemID`.

Comment: Apologies! That was actually a typo in copying on my part. I was trying to genericise the question and the called one field `Name` while the other was `CountryName` in the actual functioning applicaiton code the column and object name are both `CountryName`.  I know what you mean about expecting to see Item_ItemID but it is EF7 - so perhaps they've removed the underscore. I'll update the main question with a copy of the relevant migration code.

Comment: As per the duplicate: you have to add the join table as a class too your model. True many-to-many relations will be implemented later: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/749.

Comment: @Gert Arnold - ahhh! you're a hero!  EF7 Many to Many isn't implemented yet. I've been trying to wrap my head around the documentation of the changes to Fluent based on the only thing I could find : https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/wiki/Entity-Framework-Design-Meeting-Notes-June-5,-2014 (some meeting notes from 2014) I'm happy to just implement the relationship "the hard way" if I know I'm not just missing something.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a many to many relationship put an ICollection of Item on the country class and EF will generate the table you want.

Comment: Thanks for the tip - the good news is that the odd column is no longer appearing on the Country table, but the relationship table doesn't seem to get created.  Still digging.